# Find the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {1^n+ 2^n +\cdots +n^n \over n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {1^n+ 2^n +\cdots +n^n \over n^n}
\end{aligned}

I tried to use the O'Stolz Rule.But it didn't work.

I  was thinking about Riemann sums ,but I don't kown how to use it :(

Ps:
\begin{aligned}
a_1&=1^1\\
a_2&=1^2+2^2\\
&\vdots\\
a_n&=1^n+2^n+\cdots+n^n\\
a_{n+1}&=1^{n+1}+2^{n+1}+\cdots+n^{n+1}+(n+1)^{n+1}
\end{aligned}

Comment: After applying Stolz you get $\lim\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}-n^n}$, have you tried dividing numerator and denominator by $n^n$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $(1-k/n)^n<e^{-k}$, the limit equals $1+ \dfrac 1 e + \dfrac 1 {e^2} +\cdots=\dfrac e {e-1}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!It's the right answer.

Comment: for k<n : 1-k/n <1, the term on the left of the inequality is bigger than the one on the right, so the inequality is false. And since the left part of it is true, you can't bound exp(-k) with your suit, so the proof doesn't hold

Comment: @mvggz Thank you for correction! I edited the answer.

Comment: Your welcome :) , but I still don't see how you can affirm that the limits of both series are the same. Don't you have just : L=< e/(e-1) ?

Comment: @mvggz Exactly, my answer proves that $L\leqslant e/(e-1)$. Note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-k/n)^n$ equals $e^{-k}$, so considering the $t$ greatest terms in nominator we get $L\geqslant 1+1/e+...+1/e^t$ for any $t$.

Comment: I think there is something missing here, you can't affirm that L >=1+1/e+...+1/e^t for any t. The limit is made on n, for a given k but you can't say that if : U(n,k)--> V(k), when n--> ∞, and the series V(k) converges then the partial sum of U(n,k) does as well and both partial sums have the same limit, there is an argument missing, or at least something has to be added up. You know, it's like dominated convergence theorem

Comment: @mvggz I just mean that, for any $t$, we have $1+1/e+...+1/e^t=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {(n-t)^n+\cdots +n^n \over n^n}\leqslant \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {1^n+ 2^n +\cdots +n^n \over n^n}\leqslant1+1/e+1/e^2+...$, so the limit is $1+1/e+1/e^2+...=e/(e-1).$

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. Nice way to do it by the way, I had persuaded my mind that it was more sophisticated :)

Comment: I think that's a bug, I can't edit my answer. Use the Cesaro-Stolz theorem to prove that this answer is not a solution.(the limit is $1$)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a change of variable in the sum : $k'=n-k$

if you define:$ U(n,k) = (1-{k \over n})^n $and $V_n $ your sum, you have :

$$V_n = U(n,1) + ...+ U(n,n)$$

Now I would introduce this:$ E(x)$ is the floor of $x$

$$ U(n,k) = \int_k^{k+1}  (1-{E(x) \over n})^n dx$$

So $$V_n= \int_1^n (1-{E(x) \over n})^ndx$$  Let $ T_n$ be:  $(1-{E(x) \over n})^n$ if $ x=<n$, $ 0 $ if $x>n$

$$\Rightarrow  V_n= \int_1^{+\infty} Tn(x) dx$$

$T_n(x)$ $\rightarrow$  $e^{-E(x)}$ when $n\rightarrow  ∞$

You use the theorem that allows you to take the limit under the integrale, and you get:

$$\lim V_n = \int_1^{+\infty} e^{-E(x)} dx  = {e \over e-1} $$